# how to customize html report file generated using py.test?

Tags: python, html, pytest

I am trying to customize html report using pytest.
For example, if I've got a directory structure like:

```
tests
    temp1
         test_temp1.py
    conftest.py
```

A conftest.py file is also in the tests directory, and it should be common to all the sub-directories in the tests directory.
What fixtures and hookwrappers can I use in the conftest.py to change the contents of the html file generated using the following command:

> py.test tests/temp1/test_temp1.py --html=report.html

Comment: Are you using pytest-html plugin?

Comment: Are u able to find the solution for this? I am looking for solution.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** In latest version, if you wanna modify the **Environment** table in html report, add to your `conftest.py` next code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def configure_html_report_env(request)
    request.config._metadata.update(
        {'foo': 'bar'}
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Missing the `:` on the second line (to define the function).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using some plugin like pytest-html. 
If that is the case check documentation for that plugin for what all hooks are provided.

for pytest-html following hooks are provided
You can add change the Environment section of the report by modifying `request.config._html.environment` from a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _environment(request):
    request.config._environment.append(('foo', 'bar'))
```

You can add details to the HTML reports by creating an ‘extra’ list on the report object. The following example adds the various types of extras using a `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook, which can be implemented in a plugin or `conftest.py` file:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        # always add url to report
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra
```

Comment: Thanks, I  tried it and it worked. But, what if I want to add more html elements that the present ones? for example, I want to add tables and columns to the existing ones. Where can I get more details about it?

Comment: Code is at below location, you can modify or override the functions as per your need.
`Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytest_html`

Comment: saurabh baid, are sure that `request.config._environment.append(('foo', 'bar'))` is capable to modify **Environment** table? in the latest version of pytest-html nor `config` nor `HTMLReport` has `_environment` attr

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov this was there till 1.12.0. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-html/1.12.0